# Angularfire2 - How to remove object on disconnect?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

What's the right pattern to remove a Firebase object in Angularfire2 on server disconnect? FirebaseObjectObservable doesn't seem to provide a hook into the FirebaseOnDisconnect interface.

Comment: The Firebase JavaScript SDK has a [feature called `onDisconnect()` for such cases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#how-ondisconnect-works). If AngularFire doesn't wrap this feature, you can access the JavaScript SDK through the underlying Firebase database reference.

Comment: ok thanks; this works:    `const onDisconnectRef: FirebaseOnDisconnect = new Firebase(url).child(path).onDisconnect();`

Comment: Good to hear. Can you write up an answer with the code and how to use it in a project, so that others can benefit from it too? Self-answers are encouraged here on Stack Overflow and a good way to earn reputation.

Answer (score 4):

The `OnDisconnect` API is not supported natively by AngularFire2, however you can still pass a reference into a `FirebaseObjectObservable`.

```
constructor(af: AngularFire) {
  const ref = firebase.database().ref().child('item');
  ref.onDisconnect().remove();
  const myObjObs = af.object.list(ref);
}
```

Comment: need to import firebase first  `import firebase from 'firebase';`

Answer (score 0):

```
const onDisconnectRef: FirebaseOnDisconnect = new Firebase(url).child(path).onDisconnect();
onDisconnectRef.remove();
```

and if you need to cancel...

```
onDisconnectRef.cancel();
```

to get the firebase typescript types, do

```
typings install --save --ambient firebase
```

these are globally available in VSCode intellisense. no need to import firebase in your files (i do not understand why this is).

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use the database method to get it from AngularFireDatabase

```
   constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
      let url='/items/item';
      const ref = this.db.database.refFromUrl(url);
      ref.onDisconnect().remove();
      const myObjObs = db.object.list(url); 
    }
```